# Default Index on Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, indexing

Does SQL Server build an index on primary keys by default?
If yes what kind of index? If no what kind of index is appropriate for selections by primary key?

I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can easily determine the first part of this for yourself

```
create table x
(
id int primary key
)

select * from sys.indexes where object_id = object_id('x')
```

Gives

```
object_id   name             index_id    type type_desc                                                    is_unique data_space_id ignore_dup_key is_primary_key is_unique_constraint fill_factor is_padded is_disabled is_hypothetical allow_row_locks allow_page_locks
1653580929  PK__x__6383C8BA    1           1    CLUSTERED                                                    1         1             0              1              0                    0           0         0           0               1               1
```

**Edit:** There is one other case I should have mentioned

```
create table t2 (id int not null, cx int)

create clustered index ixc on dbo.t2 (cx asc)

alter table dbo.t2 add constraint pk_t2 primary key (id) 

select * from sys.indexes where object_id = object_id('t2')
```

Gives

```
object_id   name                           index_id    type type_desc                      is_unique data_space_id ignore_dup_key is_primary_key is_unique_constraint fill_factor is_padded is_disabled is_hypothetical allow_row_locks allow_page_locks has_filter filter_definition
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ---- ------------------------------ --------- ------------- -------------- -------------- -------------------- ----------- --------- ----------- --------------- --------------- ---------------- ---------- ------------------------------
34099162    ixc                            1           1    CLUSTERED                      0         1             0              0              0                    0           0         0           0               1               1                0          NULL
34099162    pk_t2                          2           2    NONCLUSTERED                   1         1             0              1              0                    0           0         0           0               1               1                0          NULL
```

With regard to the second part there is no golden rule it depends on your individual query workload, and what your PK is.

For satisfying individual lookups by primary key a  non clustered index will be fine. If you are doing queries against ranges these would be well served by a matching clustered index but a covering non clustered index could also suffice.

You also need to consider the index width of the clustered index in particular as it impacts all your non clustered indexes and effect of inserts on page splits.

I recommend the book [SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Server-Performance-Tuning-Distilled-Experts/dp/1430219025) to read more about the issues.

Answer (score 13):

Yes.  By default a unique clustered index is created on all primary keys, but you can create a unique nonclustered index instead of you like.

As to what the appropriate choice, I'd say that for 80-90% of the tables you create, you generally want the clustered index to be the primary key, but that's not always the case.

You'd typically make the clustered index something else if you do heavy range scans on that "something else".  For example, if you have a synthetic primary key*, but have a date column that you typically query in terms of a range, you'd often want that date column to be the most significant column in your clustered index.

*That's usually done by using an INT IDENTITY column as the PK on the table.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it builds a clustered index on the primary key by default.

Comment: Not always. If you don't specify the type of index but a clustered index already exists then creating a primary key will automatically create a NONCLUSTERED index. If you want to be sure then specify the type of index you want.

Comment: Just a note reverse is also true. If you don't specify the type of index but a non-clustered index already exists then creating a primary key will automatically create a CLUSTERED index.

Answer (score 2):

To be direct, SQL does create an index on the PRIMARY KEY (PK) keyword.  That index is a Unique, Clustered Index.

sqlvogel brings up an important point in his commoent above.  You can only have one "CLUSTERED" index.  If you already have one prior to declaring a PK then your key will be NONCLUSTERED.  This is a little more detail than the default answer to this question.  It should also be noted that PK's can not have NULL values.

Note, however that that index can vary depending on prior constraints or index on the table.  Additionally, you can declare the details of this index upon creation depending on how you write out the code:

```
< table_constraint > ::= [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] 
{ [ { PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE } 
    [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] 
    { ( column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,...n ] ) } 
    [ WITH FILLFACTOR = fillfactor ] 
    [ ON { filegroup | DEFAULT } ] 
]
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
Id INT NOT NULL,
ForeignKeyId INT REFERENCES OtherTable(Id) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Comments VARCHAR(500) NULL,

PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id, ForeignKeyId)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't in the case where there is already an index defined on the table

Comment: DVR, check the dates before you answer a question. This question was asked and answered over two years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I just come across the same confusion ,Just created a following script to test :

```
create database mytest
go
use mytest
go
create table x
(
id int primary key
)
go
create table y 
(
    id int 
)
go
select * from sys.indexes where object_id = object_id(N'x') or object_id=object_Id(N'y')
go
```

> First Table x having primary key get's the clustered index ,while table y did't get any
>   indexes ,as there is no primary key .

***Confirmed following point about clustered  Indexes :***

- When we create table with Primary Key Clustered Index will be created
  by Default
- When we create table without Primary key clustered index will not be 
  created .
- *There will be single clustered Index* ,as it depends on the Index key 
  Value . Shorting of the data rows in the table can only be in the one
  order based on Index key value .